# Simple: what's the CSS selector for this item?

Tags: html, css

sorry for this trivial question, but i just don't get it. I would like to set the witdh of this image:

```
<img class='icon weather/mostlycloudy' 
src="/fhem/images/default/weather/mostlycloudy.png" alt="mostlycloudy" 
title="mostlycloudy">
```

I've tried things like

```
[class~="weather"] {
    witdh:50px;
}

.img.icon {
    witdh:50px;
}
```

and everything I could imagine, but the width attribute never appears if I check it with chromes inspect tool. I'm sure that I edit the correct .css file, because I can see the influence for other elements of that page. I surely am no html or css expert and maybe a bit dumb... Could you please help me?

Comment: Remove the `.` before `img`

Should be `img.icon`

Comment: "width" is spelled wrong. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: You misspelled `width`, but also CSS doesn't "add attributes". It adds styling, but that won't show up as attributes in the inspection. Also a suggestion: Just add a separate `weather` class to the icon and use the `.weather` selector, instead of relying on this more complex and slower `[class~="weather"]` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code.

**First**, the selector. img is an HTML element and therefore should not be prefixed with a `.` as it was a class name. (unless you're having a class named img).

```
.img.icon {
```

Should be:

```
img.icon {
```

**Second**, you wrote `witdh` instead of `width`. You've should notice that in the inspector this property has been marked with a `!` as there's a mistake.

```
img.icon {
    width:50px; //not wi**td**h
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmztezc2/

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to all the others as well... Some days, you shouldn't mess around with code... especially if you have some fiever.

Answer (score 0):

`img.icon` (selecting the img element type) rather than `.img.icon` (which looks for a `class` containing `img`) should do the trick.

If you're looking to match any class starting with `weather/`, then I suggest `[class*="weather/"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "/" in class name.

```
<img class='icon weather mostlycloudy' ...> 

img.weather {
    witdh:50px;
}
```

Comment: You can use "/" in a class name - you just need to escape it like that: .weather\/mostlycloudy { width: 50px; } Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/27/

Answer (score -1):

`img` is tag, so you dont use coma before it. `icon` is class, so before class you use coma

```
img.icon
```

Answer (score -1):

Little change in your code

```css
[class~="weather"] {
    width:50px;
}

img.icon {
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: @Markus, made some edits in the replies. Please review and change your votes.